# (Google Sheets) Get Value from Another Spreadsheet Based On Row Info

Tags: google-sheets

I have a **spreadsheet** (A) with 1000 rows of data. **Each row as a unique ID** for example "#956"

I then have another **spreadsheet** (B) that has rows that **reference these IDs.**

My spreadsheet (A) contains columns I would like to appear in my spreadsheet (B).

***In a column within my spreadsheet (B), could I use a formula to reference specific columns of information, that appear on certain rows, within my spreadsheet (A).***

So in summary, using the unique ID's e.g. "#999" in my spreadsheet (B). I would like to reference columns of information that are in my spreadsheet (A).

Comment: possible. share a copy of your sheets with example of desired output

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All the details should be in the question. I have two spreadsheets. Both have IDs in the form "#999". I want to reference data from columns K and L inside spreadsheet A. I want these values to appear in spreadsheet B. Using the unique ID to reference the row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.
You should use Vlookup and Importrange formulas.

Importrange returns you an array and you can reference it using formulas.

Let's say that your ID's are in column A of each spreadsheet.
You are in spreadsheetA in row 5 and look for a value in spreadsheeetB with the same ID.
Your vlookup formula will look like this:

=vlookup(A5,importrange("[spreadsheetB url]","a1:z"),[index],false)

[index] - is a number of column from which you want to get a value.

You need to have access to both spreadsheets and allow access when running formula for the first time.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have tried what you said. I have both of the IDs in rows B, as the date is in row A. So I changed A5 to B309, as I'm testing on row 309. I get the error: "Did not find value '#951' in VLOOKUP evaluation."

Comment: I tried the importrange just by itself. It is successfully importing the range. Maybe because the ID's are on column B, this could be affecting it? Thank you for your help

Comment: I changed the "a1:z" to "B1:Z" and it worked! Yayyy! For the vlookup does it need to be on the first column or something?

Answer (score 1):

if unique id is in both spreadsheets in A column go for:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, IMPORTRANGE("URL_or_ID", "Sheet_name!A2:L"), {11, 12}, 0)))
```